# Selenium window handle changes after get(<html file>)

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

Window handle changes after loading an html file:

```
from selenium import webdriver

webDrv = webdriver.Firefox()
print("Window Handles after new webdriver: ", webDrv.window_handles)
```

> Window Handles after new webdriver:  ['10']

```
# base tab used for another purpose and ignored here
# open a new tab
link = "about:blank"
webDrv.execute_script("window.open('{}');".format(link))
print("Window Handles after open blank tab: ", webDrv.window_handles)
```

> Window Handles after open blank tab:  ['10', '4294967298']

```
hdl = webDrv.window_handles[-1]         # get the new handle
webDrv.switch_to.window(hdl)            # switch to the new tab
webDrv.get(r"file://C:/BasePage.html")  # open simple html
print("Window Handles after file load: ", webDrv.window_handles)
```

> Window Handles after file load:  ['10', '24']

What happened here?  Who changed the handle value?  Why?  Where in documentation?

Thanks very much!
David
Clerk, CHIFOOJobs
chifoo.org

BasePage.html is:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Base Page</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: seems like firefox makes a full window handle (uid) only after you navigate somewhere.  Looks like there's an explanation here:  https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/149

Comment: @pcalkins - Pretty surprising to have to load something before being able to pick of a reliable handle. Seems like making a new tab and getting ready to use it -- saving the handle -- is usually a whole separate set of code than opening a URL. Looks like I got too focused on opening a file (haven't done that through Selenium) and did not use a wide enough re-search term, "navigation." Anyway, thanks for the pointer and let's call this one answered.  If you will make yours a Reply, I will convert to Answer.  Cheers!

Comment: cheers!  Seems like its only the first window/tab that will begin with the 2-digit handle.  Your 2nd tab switched to that because it was a file I guess....  if it were localhost, I think you'd get the normal window handle.

Comment: @pcalkins -- If you would, please convert your analysis to something I can convert to Answered. Cheers!